# Iterate over indefinite array of deferred items

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

Say I have a very long list where each element requires an asynchronous call to fetch. I would like to write an API on top of that list so that a consumer can simply call "next()" or otherwise synchronously iterate over the list.

Ideally I would have something that looks like this:

```
while ((foo = generator.next()) != null) {
  process(foo);
}
```

But, I find myself tripping over the semantics of deferred calls, and I don't know how to escape this hard-coded pattern into a generic loop:

```
$.when(foo).then(process1AndFetch2)
  .then(process2AndFetch3)
  .then(process3AndFetch4)
  ...
```

Presumably, I could do this myself with callbacks

```
var callback = function() {
  process();
  fetch(callback);
}
fetch(callback);
```

But then my stack would get very deep, which is why I was working deferreds.

Are there any usual suspects for turning this kind of asynchronous behavior into a synchronous API?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384841/chain-ajax-and-execute-it-in-sequence-jquery-deferred/16387812#16387812). The question is phrased differently but my answer should give you some strong clues as to how to build a `.then()` chain dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have such syntax because it would just go into infinite busy loop.

There is a common promise idiom to do this:

```
var array = [process1AndFetch2, ...]

array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.then(process).then(b);
}, array.shift()()).then(function(){
    //All processed
});
```

Assumes jQuery 1.8+

Comment: Is there a place to find these common promise idioms? Or common javascript/jquery idioms?

Comment: @Sumit bluebird and Q projects have some promise stuff. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Examples-Gallery https://github.com/kriskowal/q#introduction https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#topics