# Chain ajax after another ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have struggle through this stack about my problem but still, I can't find any possible answer. Here is my problem and my current (bad) solution for it

I have an URL called **URL1**, after successfully retrieve data from this URL by ajax (called **ajax1**) , I perform another ajax (called **ajax2**) with **URL2**. If **ajax2** is successful, I need to perform **ajax1** again, with the same data with the first call. The below code is my current implementation, assume I have called **ajax1** first time successfully.

```
...
ajax1: function () {
    var ajaxPost = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: myData
    });
    return ajaxPost;
},
ajax2: function (url, data, async) {
        var ajaxPost = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            async : async
        });
        return ajaxPost;
    },
...
var ajax2 = ajax2(**URL2**, myDataObject,**false**)
ajax2.done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            ajax1();
            if(data.status === "success") {
                $('#success').html(data.message);
                $('#success').show();
            } else {
                $('#error').html(data.message);
                $('#error').show();
            }
        });
```

As we can see in the code snippet above, async of **ajax2** is set to **false**. With this implementation, after successfully return of **ajax2** and program run into .done() callback, **ajax1** can successfully perform too.

I know this implementation is bad pratice since it's blocking UI. I want to do this request asynchronously but if I set async of ajax2 to **true**, after successfully return of **ajax2** and program run into .done() callback, the **ajax1** can't send its request to server. It seems like browser blocks this request since my breakpoint in server-side can't catch anything and ajaxPost variable of **ajax2** is

> Object {readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "canceled"}

I feel like I have missed something really important and really basic, so any help would be appreciate.

****UPDATE1**** To be more specific: I can chain **ajax2** after **ajax1** by using .then() and $.Deferred(). The chain runs just like what I expect, but the ajax request of **ajax2** is still canceled by the browser. Here is the code using .then()

```
var ajax2 = ajax2(**URL2**, myDataObject,**false**)
        ajax2.done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    if(data.status === "success") {
                        $('#success').html(data.message);
                        $('#success').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#error').html(data.message);
                        $('#error').show();
                    }
                }).then(function(){
                    ajax1();
                });
```

Using $.Deferred()

```
var ajax2 = ajax2(**URL2**, myDataObject,**false**);
var dfrd = $.Deferred();
        ajax2.done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    if(data.status === "success") {
                        $('#success').html(data.message);
                        $('#success').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#error').html(data.message);
                        $('#error').show();
                    }
                    dfrd.resolve();
                })

         dfrd.then(function(){
                    ajax1();
                });
```

Comment: Never, *ever*, use `async: false`. Provide the `ajax2()` function as a callback of `ajax1()`

Comment: Hi RoryMcCrossan Could you please be more specific? As you can see, I have put ajax2() as a callback of ajax1() but it didn't work.

Comment: Your example doesn't call `ajax1()`, and it doesn't accept any callback params? There's plenty of examples of how to do this if you search, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384841/chain-ajax-and-execute-it-in-sequence-jquery-deferred

Comment: I thought that using **.done()** is equivalent with **successful:** declaration of $.ajax()? I have tried **successful:** declaration of **$.ajax()**, though. But it didn't work, the request is still canceled by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use result from last ajax to hold the control in ajax2.done(). Like this:

```
var ajax2 = ajax2(**URL2**, myDataObject)
        ajax2.done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
               var result = ajax1();
               result.done(function(){
                    if(data.status === "success") {
                        $('#success').html(data.message);
                        $('#success').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#error').html(data.message);
                        $('#error').show();
                    }
               });
           });
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I have done something similar to your answer but it didn't work. I have edit ed my post to be more specific about this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stops by, I have resolved this problem.

```
...
ajax1: function () {
    var ajaxPost = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: myData
    });
    return ajaxPost;
},
ajax2: function (url, data, async) {
        var ajaxPost = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            async : async
        });
        return ajaxPost;
    },
...
var ajax2 = ajax2(**URL2**, myDataObject,**false**)
ajax2.done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                ajax1();
            }, 0);
            if(data.status === "success") {
                $('#success').html(data.message);
                $('#success').show();
            } else {
                $('#error').html(data.message);
                $('#error').show();
            }
        });
```

The `setTimeout` magic comes to rescue. ***I don't really know why this solution work***. By my inspection so far, it seems that `.done()` call back is not ***done*** enough, there is something that browser still needs to process after `ajax2()` finishes. When `ajax1()` is called in `.done()` call back, browser simply reject this request because it still hasn't done its business with `ajax2()` yet.
By using `setTimeout`, I place `ajax1()` at the end of execution queue, thus providing browser with time to complete everything before execute `ajax1()`.