# Mutiple ajax requests

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a bunch of ajax requests but I need them to run one at a time.
The below only seems to work on the first object and I think it's because it's trying to run everything at the one time.

```
$(fullurllist).each(function(index,element){
    runAjax(element.url)    
})
function runAjax(dataURL){
    $.ajax({
        url:dataURL,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept":  "application/json; odata=verbose"  },
        success: function  (data) {}
    })
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered.... Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384841/chain-ajax-and-execute-it-in-sequence-jquery-deferred

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chain ajax and execute it in sequence. Jquery Deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384841/chain-ajax-and-execute-it-in-sequence-jquery-deferred)